How to add a pull request check for a different repo's pipeline
My primary repo "MainApp" has 3 different .NET projects and the master branch is called develop. Each project has its own pipeline therefore I've setup build validations for the branch to ensure each projects pipeline is included as a PR check.
I have another repo "SecondApp", with a master branch and its own pipeline SecondApp-Build.
One of the MainApp's pipeline triggers a run of SecondApp-Build using Azure REST API (open to alternatives).
How can I include this pipeline as a PR check for MainApp's branch?

Based on your description, the Pipeline: SecondApp-Build is using different repos and triggered by MainApp's pipeline. In this case, the Pipeline status can not directly be used in the Pull Request.

How can I include this pipeline as a PR check for MainApp's branch?

You can use Pull Request Status check and Azure DevOps Rest API: Pull Request Statuses - Create to achieve it.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Add the Status check to MainApp repo Branch Ploicy. And set the Genre and Name value.
For example:
Genre: vsts-samples
Name: status-check-SecondApp-Build

Step2: You need to set the parameters in SecondApp-Build Pipeline to collect the Pull Request ID. Then when you use MainApp's pipeline to trigger pipeline, you need to pass Pull Reuqest ID value via Rest API.
For example:
MainApp's Pipeline Powershell:
$token = "$(pat)"      
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{organizationname}/{ProjectName}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelineID}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
      
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      
      $JSON = "
      {
        
      
      
        `"resources`": {
          `"repositories`": {
            `"self`": {
              `"ref`": `"refs/heads/main`"
            }
          }
        },
        `"templateParameters`": {
          `"PullRequestID`":`"$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)`"
        },
      
      
      
      }"
      
      
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

SecondApp-Build Pipeline:
parameters:
  - name: PullRequestID
    type: string
    default: 1

Step3: You can use script to run Rest API to pass the Pipeline status to Pull Request status check.
Here is an Powershell example:
  $token = "$(PAT)"
      
      
      
  $url="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/databricks/pullRequests/${{parameters.PullRequestID}}/statuses?api-version=7.2-preview.2"
  
  $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
  
    $JSON = "

    {
      `"state`": `"succeeded`",
      `"description`": `"Sample status succeeded`",
      `"context`": {
        `"name`": `"status-check-SecondApp-Build`",
        `"genre`": `"vsts-samples`"
      },
      `"targetUrl`": `"https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_build/results?buildId=$(build.buildid)&view=results`"
    }

    "
  
  $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

You can set the Status check Result based on the condition.
Full YAML sample:
parameters:
  - name: PullRequestID
    type: string
    default: 1
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
steps:
.....
- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: failed()
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      env | sort
      $token = "$(PAT)"
      
      
      
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/databricks/pullRequests/${{parameters.PullRequestID}}/statuses?api-version=7.2-preview.2"
      
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      
        $JSON = "

        {
          `"state`": `"failed`",
          `"description`": `"Sample status failed`",
          `"context`": {
            `"name`": `"status-check-SecondApp-Build`",
            `"genre`": `"vsts-samples`"
          },
          `"targetUrl`": `"https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_build/results?buildId=$(build.buildid)&view=results`"
        }

        "
      
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: succeeded()
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      env | sort
      $token = "$(PAT)"
      
      
      
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/databricks/pullRequests/${{parameters.PullRequestID}}/statuses?api-version=7.2-preview.2"
      
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      
        $JSON = "

        {
          `"state`": `"succeeded`",
          `"description`": `"Sample status succeeded`",
          `"context`": {
            `"name`": `"status-check-SecondApp-Build`",
            `"genre`": `"vsts-samples`"
          },
          `"targetUrl`": `"https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_build/results?buildId=$(build.buildid)&view=results`"
        }

        "
      
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

Result:
When the SecondApp-Build is failed/successed, it will send result to Pull Request status check.

At the same time, you can click the link in status check to navigate to the target Pipeline Run.

Thank you. Wish there was a task that could do this instead of adding so many scripts though.

Agree. But there is no task that can implement this feature directly for the time being. We need to rely on scripts.
